VS Code Color Setting for Matched Text in Menus
I'm trying to change the text-match color in VS Code menus, but I can't find the setting documented anywhere.
How can I update the color off the text inside these pink boxes?


It is list.highlightForeground in your colorCustomizations in your settinbgs.json file.
